# How to calculate accuracy of latitude/longitude

Tags: c#, gps, windows

I'm updating a Windows Mobile application to capture location information using the built-in GPS hardware. The Microsoft API provides a method *GPSGetPosition* that returns the following struct (ref:[GPS_POSITION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb202062.aspx)):

```
typedef struct _GPS_POSITION {
    DWORD dwVersion;
    DWORD dwSize;
    DWORD dwValidFields;
    DWORD dwFlags;
    SYSTEMTIME stUTCTime;
    double dblLatitude;
    double dblLongitude;
    float  flSpeed;
    float  flHeading;
    double dblMagneticVariation;
    float  flAltitudeWRTSeaLevel;
    float  flAltitudeWRTEllipsoid;
    GPS_FIX_QUALITY     FixQuality;
    GPS_FIX_TYPE        FixType;
    GPS_FIX_SELECTION   SelectionType;
    float flPositionDilutionOfPrecision;
    float flHorizontalDilutionOfPrecision;
    float flVerticalDilutionOfPrecision;
    DWORD dwSatelliteCount;
    DWORD rgdwSatellitesUsedPRNs[GPS_MAX_SATELLITES];
    DWORD dwSatellitesInView;
    DWORD rgdwSatellitesInViewPRNs[GPS_MAX_SATELLITES];
    DWORD rgdwSatellitesInViewElevation[GPS_MAX_SATELLITES];
    DWORD rgdwSatellitesInViewAzimuth[GPS_MAX_SATELLITES];
    DWORD rgdwSatellitesInViewSignalToNoiseRatio[GPS_MAX_SATELLITES];
} GPS_POSITION, *PGPS_POSITION;
```

So I can determine the latitude and longitude but I would like to be able to calculate the accuracy of the result. The application runs on a Trimble Juno and the *GPS Controller* application on the device provides an accuracy value in metres. Is this something I can determine from the values in the struct or is this something specific to the hardware that would require a native function call? Is the accuracy value based on heuristics or is it a common calculation across different hardware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dilution of precision is a representation of accuracy, however, it's not in meters. Have you seen [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb202062.aspx) page with descriptions of each property of your struct?

Here is an explanation of the [DOP scale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilution_of_precision_%28GPS%29) and how it's calculated from actual measurements.

Comment: WRT your question, I put that link at the top of my question so yes, I have seen that page - it was where I sourced the struct definition. Thanks for the DOP link. I'm still in the dark as to how to calculate accuracy in metres from the DOP values. Is there anywhere else I could look for this info or is it specific to a particular GPS hardware/vendor?

Comment: I've discussed with one of our local GIS guys and I'm going to use PDOP as a measure of accuracy instead of trying to convert it to metres. For my application, anything below PDOP of 6 is valid but less then 2 is better. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @DavidClarke aww too bad, I was looking for the same answer, because I need to talk to an API that requires accuracy in metres (for gameplay validation)…